# Filter for top 10 highest values of group in dataset (in R)

Tags: r, data-wrangling

**Context**: I am trying to find the top 10 highest values of count in my data frame conditional on them falling within the years 1970-1979. My data frame looks as below:

```
id    lemma    year    count    
1     word1    1970    737 
2     word2    1971    767
3     word3    1972    988
```

etc...

**Attempt**:

```
#1970s
df_n_maxcount_1970s <- df_n %>% filter(year < 1980) %>% slice_max(count, n=40)

#1990s
df_n_maxcount_1980s <- df_n %>% filter(year == 1980:1989) %>% slice_max(count, n=40)
```

This has worked pretty well, but there's a level of manual work and in 1990 I had to increase n to 200 because there were many duplicates (i.e., the same word was appearing many times so I wasn't getting 10 unique words when searching for the top 10 with n=10).

**Question**: Can I automate the code so that I end up with one dataframe arranged as below? (of course, word 1 in 1970 might not equal word1 in 1980 and there would be 10 rows for each decade value for the top 10 words arranged by count). OR at least 5 separate dataframes with top 10 counts of words per decade?

````
decade lemma count    
1970   word1 100
1970   word2 99
1970   word3 98
1980   word1 100
1990   word1 100
2000   word1 100
2010   word1 100
```
````

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `dplyr` and a combination of `group_by` and aggregations functions. Something like this should work:

```
library(dplyr)

df_n <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3),
  lemma = c("word1", "word2", "word3"),
  year = c(1970, 1971, 1972), 
  count = c(737, 767, 988)
)

df_n %>%
    # create column that specifies the decade
    mutate(decade = year - year %% 10) %>%
    group_by(decade, lemma) %>%
    # add up counts for duplicate words within groups specified above
    summarise(count = sum(count)) %>%
    group_by(decade) %>%
    # select top 10 records based on count within groups specified above
    top_n(10, count)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The code isn't working but I assume I have to play around with it. I'm wondering if this line is however supposed to be something else?     mutate(decade = year - year %% 10) %>%

Comment: @n.baes What error do you get when trying to run the code? It works perfectly fine on my end using the minimum working example you provided (see also my edit).